# How to play sound on app start

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to set a background music in my app. Im using a mediaplayer but it does not work in onCreate method. Is there any other ways to do that?

Code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mediaPlayer.start();

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

    }
```

Comment: MediaPlayer should suit your needs, you should post your code so we can see the issue. And also look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's not working? Logcat would be helpful!

Comment: This code worked for me 
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
mediaPlayer.start();

Comment: I hope you provide the user the ability to disable that music.